# PHP Sessions Redirection

Tags: php

I made a login system and want to create different sessions for different users and give them a personalized dashboard.

When logged in, users are redirected to dashboard.php. In dashboard.php, I want to check if username is "SARTHAK"(Should cross-check from database), the user should be redirected to file1.php. If user is "STEVE", he should be redirected to page2.php. Otherwise the user should be redirected to default.php.

I know that I have asked this question earlier but the methods did not work.

Comment: rather then lead them to dashboard.php to do the redirect, why dont you do it when you auth the user? if username == "xxx" redirect else redirect to dashboard.php

Comment: You have to make your sessions work first, dude

Answer (score 3):

**What you need to do:** post your code.

**What you don't need to:** redirect these users to different pages. Instead, you can use the username (or user id, whatever your schema) to construct a personalized dashboard. This is exactly how the majority of web apps handle this.

You said you've asked this question before, [but the only other question you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791125/help-with-php-session-start) does not seem related to this.

Unless and until you post your code, it will be difficult to help.

Comment: though i agree with this guy, u should keep all the content on one page, and just show different stuff depending on the user

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start()
$redirect = 'default.php';
if ($_SESSION['user'] == 'SARTHAK') $redirect = 'file1.php';
if ($_SESSION['user'] == 'STEVE') $redirect = 'page2.php';
header("Location: $redirect");
```

should do it

Comment: thanks for the response. no matter what the username is, it takes me to default.php. Thanks

Comment: are u sure the username is being stored?

Comment: Do a echo "<pre>".print_r($_SESSION,true)."</pre>"; after the session start and see if its there

Comment: Actually, @Ascherer and @Sarthak, you should be using `var_dump()` over `print_r()` here. The former often gets you far more information than the latter.

Comment: yeah, i use var_dump sometimes, but the user should show up in print_r

Comment: It should, but if he did something wrong and `$_SESSION` is `null`, then `var_dump()` will show it without needing the extra effort of the `true` param in `print_r()`.

Comment: hey, i just used echo "<pre>".print_r($_SESSION,true)."</pre>";

Comment: and removed the above code. Now with ony echo "<pre>".print_r($_SESSION,true)."</pre>"; as the code, i am getting a notice that says - Undefined index username and password.

Comment: I am sorry to bother you, but can you please re-explain.

Comment: @Josh Smith thats not too much extra effort, but you are right. 
@Sarthak you would need session_start() before you print it IIRC. Im just trying to figure out what variables the username and password are stored as.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?PHP 
session_start();

$_SESSION['username'] = "SARTHAK";
echo $_SESSION['username'];

if ($_SESSION['username'] == "SARTHAK") {
 header("location:file1.php");
}
else if ($_SESSION['username'] == "STEVE") {
 header("location:page2.php");
}
else {
 header("location:default.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: no matter what the username is, it takes me to default.php. Thanks

Comment: don't know what the problem is, i've edit my previous answer, try it. if the problem persist you can post you code